# Black screen flashes between Launch and first ViewController in SceneDelegate

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am using SceneDelegate.swift to decide which ViewController is shown with this code:

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {

        AuthenticationService.automaticSignIn(onSuccess: {

            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            self.window = window
            let mainstoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
            let newViewcontroller:UIViewController = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarControllerID") as! TabBarController
            window.rootViewController = newViewcontroller
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }, onError: {

            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            self.window = window
            let mainstoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
            let newViewcontroller:UIViewController = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewControllerID") as! LoginViewController
            window.rootViewController = newViewcontroller
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        })
    } else {

        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        self.window = window
        let mainstoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
        let newViewcontroller:UIViewController = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewControllerID") as! LoginViewController
        window.rootViewController = newViewcontroller
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Between the transition, a black screen appears (in my .gif for about 0.2 seconds), depending on the loading time. Sorry for the bad quality and the short duration, but you will see it:

[image]

Where does this black screen come from?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue, setting ViewController depending on authorization status and getting the black flicker.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line:-
self.window!.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: DashboardVC)
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be caused by a 'gap' in the presentation between the launch-storyboard and the window that is made visible. The appleIDProvider is async.

A workaround, rather than a fix, is to present a temporary View (with the same color or content as your launch-storyboard) and replace it once authorization is done;

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: TempView())
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let user = User.shared
    let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()

    appleIDProvider.getCredentialState(forUserID: user.id) { (credentialState, error) in
        switch credentialState {
        case .authorized:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                user.authenticated =  true
                window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: HomeView(showAlert: false, showSendview: false, showAccountview: false))
            }
        default:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                user.authenticated = false
                window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: SignInView().environment(\.window, window))
            }
        }
    }
}
```